# Python: problems with csvwriter

Tags: python, csv

I am attempting to write data (mostly dates, booleans and float data types) into a CSV file format. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
# Write data to file
with open(OUTPUT_DIR + output_filename,'w') as outputfile:
    wrtr = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

    for x, y in datarows.items():
        a,b,c,d,e,f,g = (somedate.strft('%Y-%m-%d'),0,6058.7,False,1913736200,0,False)                     
        rowstr = "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}".format(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
        wrtr.writerow(rowstr)

    outputfile.close()
```

File contents look like this:

> 2,0,0,7,-,10,-,03,",",0,",",6,0,5,8,.,7,",",F,a,l,s,e,",",1,9,1,3,7,3,6,2,0,0,",",0,",",F,a,l,s,e

I am currently using the raw file object to write to file - but I would prefer to use the csvwrite - since that is what its supposed to be used for

Comment: Can you clarify what your problem is?

Comment: that's an awful code, why are you closing `outputfile` when you're using `with` statement? what this `datarows` for loop is for?

Comment: @Mike, @Michael, each character became a separate value in CSV, so instead of 7 columns there are many more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at this example maybe it can help you:

```
import datetime

with open('file.csv','w') as outputfile:
    wrtr = csv.writer(outputfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    a = (datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),0,6058.7,False,1913736200,0,False)
    wrtr.writerow(a)  # pass an iterable here

    # outputfile.close() you don't have to call close() because you use with
```

file.csv

```
2010-11-01,0,6058.7,False,1913736200,0,False
```

hope this can help you

Answer (score 5):

Try `wrtr.writerow([a,b,c,d,e,f,g])` instead.

`writerow()` parameter must be a list of values, not a text line. The idea of `csv.writer` is that it will format row values according to CSV rules.

The result you have is due to the fact that `writerow()` interpreted your `rowstr` string as a list of characters.